# Codeigniter removes tab character from post variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

`$mgmac = $this->input->post("mgmac");`

Data got tab space. But codeigniter remove it.How can I allow to tab character.

I made false this

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Tried to this

```
$mgmac = $this->input->post("mgmac",FALSE);
```

I made

```
$str = str_replace("\t", ' ', $str);
```

into the comment line in `system\core\Security.php`.

But keep removing tab character in data.

Comment: have you loaded the html helper ?

Comment: are you sure the client who sends the data does not remove it? the last one (Security.php amendment) should be a bullet proof one

Comment: ...Not loaded..

Comment: Count the characters using `strlen` to see if it is in fact being removed. Browser might render text without tab.

Comment: @jabko87 Yes I am sure.I have same project in .net.I checked data has tab char.

Comment: you may try to use preg_replace("/\t+/", "", $str);  in Security.php

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: @Brian Gottier 3.1.6

Comment: In the code that you have provided, there really is nothing in CodeIgniter that would strip out horizontal tabs. In fact, the remove_invisible_characters function specifically allows them.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in CodeIgniter that would be stripping out your horizontal tabs. It has to be something else. Take the following code as an example. This is a method that I put into a Test controller, and you can simply copy and paste it to see that once posted the value of `mgmac` still has the tab in it.

I've also provided an image, showing the result after I click the submit button.

You can actually trace what happens to $_POST data by opening up the system/core/Input.php file. The constructor of the Input class calls `_sanitize_globals()`, which calls `_clean_input_data()` on your posted value. `remove_invisible_characters` is called to remove most invisible characters, but the horizontal tab is not one of them. Later, when you call `post()`, the `_fetch_from_array()` method retrieves the post data you are asking for. `xss_clean` will run if the second parameter of `post()` is set to TRUE, but in your case the value of mgmac should be returned untouched.

```
/**
 * This method is in my Test.php controller. I am using mod_rewrite to 
 * remove the index.php from the URL.
 */
public function tab_in_post()
{
    $val = "1\t2\t3\t4";

    echo '<form method="post" action="/test/tab_in_post">
        <input type="text" value="' . $val . '" name="mgmac" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>';

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $this->input->post('mgmac', FALSE) );
    echo '</pre>';
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]